# Strapi /dashboard page gives 404 error on VPS Hostinger

Tags: node.js, http-status-code-404, strapi, vps

I have a VPS at Hostinger running with Strapi and also the frontend on NextJs. However, after a while the Strapi dashboard (admin) started to return 404 when trying to open the page, whereas before it was opening normally.

Both Node systems, NextJs and Strapi, are running separately and are controlled via pm2.

This is the admin.ts file:

```
export default ({ env }) => ({
    url: "/dashboard",
    autoOpen: false,
    auth: {
    secret: env("ADMIN_JWT_SECRET"),
  },
  apiToken: {
    salt: env("API_TOKEN_SALT"),
  },
  transfer: {
    token: {
      salt: env("TRANSFER_TOKEN_SALT"),
    },
  },
});
```

This is the server.ts file:

```
`export default ({ env }) => ({
  host: env("HOST", "0.0.0.0"),
  port: env.int("PORT", 1337),
  app: {
    keys: env.array("APP_KEYS"),
  },
  webhooks: {
    populateRelations: env.bool("WEBHOOKS_POPULATE_RELATIONS", false),
  },
  proxy:true,
 url: env("URL", ""),
});
```

The Nginx file:

```
server {
  listen 80;
  listen [::]:80;
  listen 443 ssl http2;
  listen [::]:443 ssl http2;
  {{ssl_certificate_key}}
  {{ssl_certificate}}
  server_name www.canalspeakout.com;
  return 301 https://canalspeakout.com$request_uri;
}

server {
  listen 80;
  listen [::]:80;
  listen 443 ssl http2;
  listen [::]:443 ssl http2;
  {{ssl_certificate_key}}
  {{ssl_certificate}}
  server_name canalspeakout.com www1.canalspeakout.com;
  {{root}}

  {{nginx_access_log}}
  {{nginx_error_log}}

  if ($scheme != "https") {
    rewrite ^ https://$host$uri permanent;
  }

  location ~ /.well-known {
    auth_basic off;
    allow all;
  }

  {{settings}}

  index index.html;

  location /api {
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:{{app_port}};
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Server $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection "Upgrade";
    proxy_pass_request_headers on;
    proxy_max_temp_file_size 0;
    proxy_connect_timeout 900;
    proxy_send_timeout 900;
    proxy_read_timeout 900;
    proxy_buffer_size 128k;
    proxy_buffers 4 256k;
    proxy_busy_buffers_size 256k;
    proxy_temp_file_write_size 256k;
  }
  
   location / {
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3000;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Server $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection "Upgrade";
    proxy_pass_request_headers on;
    proxy_max_temp_file_size 0;
    proxy_connect_timeout 900;
    proxy_send_timeout 900;
    proxy_read_timeout 900;
    proxy_buffer_size 128k;
    proxy_buffers 4 256k;
    proxy_busy_buffers_size 256k;
    proxy_temp_file_write_size 256k;
  }
}
```

[The page error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TsXl1.png)

and I have an  ecosystem.config.js

```
module.exports = {
  apps : [{
    name   : "ServerStrapi",
    script : "yarn",
    args: 'start',
    autorestart: true
  }]
}
```

I ran yarn develop again, but the problem remains.

The interesting thing is that only the Strapi admin panel has this problem, everything else in the project is normal.

This is the strapi dependencies:

```
"dependencies": {
    "@strapi/plugin-documentation": "^4.9.0",
    "@strapi/plugin-i18n": "4.9.0",
    "@strapi/plugin-users-permissions": "4.9.0",
    "@strapi/provider-email-sendgrid": "^4.10.5",
    "@strapi/provider-upload-aws-s3": "^4.10.5",
    "@strapi/provider-upload-cloudinary": "^4.15.2",
    "@strapi/provider-upload-local": "^4.15.0",
    "@strapi/strapi": "4.9.0",
    "jsonwebtoken": "^9.0.2",
    "mysql": "2.18.1",
    "sharp": "^0.32.0",
    "strapi-plugin-multi-select": "^1.1.0",
    "strapi-plugin-timezone-select": "^1.0.0",
    "strapi-plugin-transformer": "^3.1.0"
  },
```